# Dialog window does not support add-in for the new Outlook for Mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Our clients are using new Outlook design 16.42 (20101102)
Our Add-in uses functions: reply/replyAll/forward they open Dialog window(pop-up) and this window does not support add-ins.
This is really critical issue, because our clients use pinned panel of add-ins to complete their workflow.
Could you please clarify when can we use the add-in inside Dialog window for european region?

Comment: Microsoft team has been fixed this issue.